# How to get the access token to a Facebook page from the link with Spring Social?

Tags: java, spring-boot, facebook-page, spring-social-facebook

I have to get a management token from a page from the link provided by the user. Until then I have collected the username of the page as a substring from the provided link and request permission from the user as follows:

```
    public String createFacebookAuthorizationURL(String pagename, Long churchId) {
        FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory(facebookAppId, facebookSecret);
        OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
        OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
        params.setRedirectUri("https://" + this.hostName + "/api/facebook/" + churchId + "/response"); params.setScope("public_profile,pages_show_list,publish_pages,manage_pages,user_events");

        return oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(params);
    }
public String createFacebookAccessToken(String code, Long churchId) {
    FacebookConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new FacebookConnectionFactory(facebookAppId, facebookSecret);
    AccessGrant accessGrant = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().exchangeForAccess(code, "https://" + this.hostName + "/api/facebook/" + churchId + "/response", null);
    return  accessGrant.getAccessToken();
}
```

I have already tested the above method and it works. The problem is that: this method requests a token for access to user pages, I want access to only one page, but I do not know how to put this in the requisitiond and token.

I want use this permissions to post text, links and images in fb pages via my system API...

Comment: It is my understanding that the only time you need an authorization token is when your app is accessing data that is restricted to a subset FB users. In this case it looks like you're accessing a church's public fb page. If that's a private page you need an access token from some user that has access to that church's page. You get this access token from the client side; the javascript side of the project sends the token over via a query parameter to your web server and you use it to get data. Can you add some info about your app? is it a web server?

Comment: @Calicoder Yes. Its a web server. I want this token to post text, links and images on the church page, via my system API. O usuário me fornece apenas o link da página da igreja. I will add more information in the question...